# ComboBox Text ValueConverter Lag - C# WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, ivalueconverter

I currently have a combobox in my WPF application, but it seems like there's some lag before the value is converted.

The value converter converts a UUID/GUID to a name, but what shows up on the combobox is first the UUID/GUID for a split second and then the name shows up.

Here's a boiled down version of my combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox"
          Text="{Binding Path=GUID, Converter={StaticResource GUIDToNameValueConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"
          Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static myNameSpace:MyItems}, Path=Items}"
          SelectionChanged="MyChangedEventHandler">
</ComboBox>
```

Here's the general gist of my valueconverter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string GUID = (string)value;
        MyObject myObject = GetObjectById(GUID);
        return myObject.name;
    }
```

Essentially, I want to get rid of the split second display of the GUID before the actual name shows up. I'm unsure why the GUID event shows up since the converter takes care of converting that to a name.

Let me know if this is enough information to have this question answered, if not, please request more parts of my code!

Comment: How is your ItemTemplate (MyTemplate) defined?

Comment: MyTemplate is defined like this:
`<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GUIDToNameValueConverter}}"
                           Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=MyComboBox}"
            </DataTemplate>`

Comment: Don't bind or set the `Text` property if you define an `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: Hey @mm8, when I remove the `Text` property on `MyComboBox`, the drop down still works fine (all the values are converted from GUID to name), but the combobox display now only displays the GUID as opposed to the name.

Comment: What if you remove `Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"`?

Comment: Oof. That did it. Thank you! Onwards to figure out what's wrong the `MyStyle` then.